# How to select distinct from two tables and then join them

Tags: sql, join, distinct

I've seen similar questions, but none of the fits my issue.

I have two tables:

WorkTable

| WorkCode | WorkDescription |
| --- | --- |
| 220001 | WorkDescription1 |
| 220002 | WorkDescription2 |
| 220003 | WorkDescription3 |
| 220004 | WorkDescription4 |

TasksTable

| TaskCode | WorkCode | TaskDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AV0001 |  | TaskDescription1 |
| AV0002 | 220002 | TaskDescription2 |
| AV0003 | 220003 | TaskDescription3 |
| AV0004 | 220003 | TaskDescription4 |

I need to get this results

ResultTable

| TaskCode | WorkCode | TaskDescription | WorkDescription |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 220001 |  |  | WorkDescription1 |
|  | AV0001 | TaskDescription1 |  |
| 220002 | AV0002 | TaskDescription2 | WorkDescription2 |
| 220003 | AV0003 | TaskDescription3 | WorkDescription3 |
| 220003 | AV0004 | TaskDescription4 | WorkDescription3 |
| 220004 |  |  | WorkDescription4 |

I've tried several queries, but it lefts out the TaskCodes that have no WorkCode associated:

WrongResultTable

| TaskCode | WorkCode | TaskDescription | WorkDescription |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 220001 |  |  | WorkDescription1 |
| 220002 | AV0002 | TaskDescription2 | WorkDescription2 |
| 220003 | AV0003 | TaskDescription3 | WorkDescription3 |
| 220003 | AV0004 | TaskDescription4 | WorkDescription3 |
| 220004 |  |  | WorkDescription4 |

Can someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.

Comment: Why do you need DISTINCT? There are no duplicates in your data...  Also, which database are you using? The vast majority support `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but a few do not.

Comment: @MatBailie that was the case.  I was keeping DISTINCT from another sql query I was based on and it was not needed.  As you say, I tried with full outer join and it worked.  I was doing something wrong, but I solved it and it works as intended.  Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's not very elegant, but see below.

```
--This section is just creating the temp tables with the data you provided.
DECLARE @WorkTable TABLE (
WorkCode INT, 
WorkDescription NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @WorkTable (WorkCode, WorkDescription)
VALUES (220001, 'WorkDescription1') , (220002, 'WorkDescription2'), (220003, 'WorkDescription3'),  (220004, 'WorkDescription4')


DECLARE @TasksTable TABLE (
TaskCode NVARCHAR(50), 
WorkCode INT ,
TaskDescription NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @TasksTable (TaskCode, WorkCode, TaskDescription)
VALUES ('AV0001', NULL, 'TaskDescription1') , ('AV0002', 220002, 'TaskDescription2'), ('AV0003', 220003, 'TaskDescription3'),  ('AV0004', 220003, 'TaskDescription4')

;

--Actual SQL query starts here
WITH a as (
select distinct w.WorkCode, t.TaskCode, t.TaskDescription, w.WorkDescription
from @WorkTable w
LEFT JOIN @TasksTable t
    on t.WorkCode = w.WorkCode) ,

b as (
SELECT distinct a.WorkCode, tt.TaskCode, tt.TaskDescription, a.WorkDescription
FROM @TasksTable tt
left join a 
        on tt.WorkCode = a.WorkCode) ,

c as (
     
select *
from a

union all 

select *
from b)

select distinct c.WorkCode, c.TaskCode, c.TaskDescription, c.WorkDescription
from c
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time answering my question.  @MatBailie answer was spot on, but your also works although, as you pointed out, is a bit more convoluted.